# how to find continuous blank lines and convert them to one

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file -- a, and exist some continues blank line(more than one), see below:

```
cat a
1

2


3



4

5
```

So first I want to know if exist continues blank lines,  I tried

```
cat a | grep '\n\n\n'
```

nothing output. So I have to use below manner

```
vi a 
:set list
/\n\n\n
```

So I want to know if exist other shell command could easily implement this? 
then if exist two and more blank lines I want to convert them to one? see below

```
1

2

3

4

5
```

at first I tried below shell

```
sed 's/\n\n\(\n\)*/\n\n/g' a
```

it does not work, then I tried this shell

```
cat a | tr '\n' '$' | sed 's/$$\(\$\)*/$$/g' | tr '$' '\n'
```

this time it works. And also I want to know if exist other manner could implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if your `cat` implementation supports

```
   -s, --squeeze-blank
          suppress repeated empty output lines
```

then it is as simple as

```
$ cat -s a
1

2

3

4

5
```

Also, both `-s` and `-n` for numbering lines is likely to be available with `less` command as well.

*remark:* lines containing only blanks will not be suppressed.

If your `cat` does not support `-s` then you could use:

```
awk 'NF||p; {p=NF}'
```

or if you want to guarantee a blank line after every record, including at the end of the output even if none was present in the input, then:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '1'
```

If your input contains lines of all white space and you want them to be treated just like lines of non white space (like `cat -s` does, see the comments below) then:

```
awk '/./||p; {p=/./}'
```

and to guarantee a blank line at the end of the output:

```
awk '/./||p; {p=/./} END{if (p) print ""}'
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this option in `cat`. ++

Comment: Seems like there is still a purpose to `cat`.

Comment: There's several, e.g. `cat -n`, `cat -v`, `cat file1 file2`, etc. It's not that `cat` is useless, it's just that some people use it in a useless context of `cat file | cmd`.

Comment: Note, that `cat -s` and the presented `awk` solution behave differently.  Imagine a set of blanks on a line. awk will remove it, cat will keep it.

Comment: Fair enough, I've added an alternative if there can be lines of blanks that need to be treated as non-empty lines.

Answer (score 3):

This `awk` command should work to produce an output with 2 line breaks at each line:

```
awk -v RS= '{printf "%s%s", $0, ORS (RT ~ /\n{2,}/ ? ORS : "")}' file

1

2

3

4

5
```

This awk is using:

- `-v RS=`: sets empty input record separator so that each empty line becomes record separator
- `printf "%s%s", $0, ORS`: prints each line with single line break
- `(RT ~ /\n{2,}/ ? ORS : "")`: prints additional line break if input record separator has more than 2 line breaks

---

You may use `perl` as well in slurp mode:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\R{2,}/\n\n/g' file

1

2

3

4

5
```

**Command breakup:**

- `-0777` Slurp mode to read entire file
- `'s/\R{2,}/\n\n/g'` Match 2 or more line breaks and replace by 2 line breaks

Comment: idk what the perl script does (who does :-) ) but the one issue with the awk one is it'll add a blank line at the end of the output even if none was present at the end of the input. With GNU awk you can solve that by testing `RT` if it's an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can `--squeeze-repeats` with `tr` and then use `sed` to insert just a new line:

```
 <a tr -s '\n' | sed 'G'
```

Comment: but it cannot conserve these lines which does not has blank lines between them, e.g. 6\n7\n8

Answer (score 1):

*remark:* This is a copy from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52533403/8344060)

---

A very quick way is using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n"}1'
```

How does this work:

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) knowns the concept records (which is by default lines) and you can define a record by its record separator `RS`. If you set the value of `RS` to an empty string, it will match any multitude of empty lines as a record separator. The value `ORS` is the output record separator. It states which separator should be printed between two consecutive records. This is set to two <newline> characters. Finally, the statement `1` is a shorthand for `{print $0}` which prints the current record followed by the output record-separator `ORS`.

**note:** This will, just as `cat -s` keep lines with only blanks as actual lines and will not suppress them.

Comment: ... but unlike `cat -s` it will add a blank line at the end of the output even if that wasn't present in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk solution:

```
awk 'NF' ORS="\n\n" a
1

2

3

4

5
```

It checks if the line is not empty by testing if NF (number of fields) is not zero. It it matches, print the line as default action. ORS (output record separator) is set to 2 newline characters, so there is an empty line between non-empty lines.

Comment: but I found even there is no blank lines among non-empty lines, e.g. `6\n7\n8` , they are also inserted new line between them.

Answer (score 0):

**1) awk solution**

```
$ echo "a\n\n\nb\n\n\nc\n\n\n" | awk 'BEGIN{b=0} /^$/{b=1;next} {printf "%s%s\n", b==1?"\n":"",$0} {b=0} END{printf "%s",b==1?"\n":""}'
        a

        b

        c

$
```

**2) sed solution**

```
sed '

/^$/{ ${ p; d; }; H; d; } 

/^$/!{ x; s/^\(\n\{1,\}\)$/\1/; ts; Tf; } 

:s { x; s/\(.*\)/\n\1/; x; s/.*//; x; p; d; } 

:f { x; p; d; }

'
```

**SED Explanation:**

```
/^$/{ ${ p; d; }; H; d; }
```

--If input is blank, if it is the last line, just print, else append to the holdspace and delete the pattern space and start new cycle

```
/^$/!{ x; s/^\(\n\{1,\}\)$/\1/; ts; Tf; }
```

--If input is not blank, exchange content of the p space and h space and check if h space contains \n. if yes, jump to s, if not jump to f

```
:s { x; s/\(.*\)/\n\1/; x; s/.*//; x; p; d; }
```

--If blank lines are present in h space, then append \n to p space, then clear hold space , then print p space and delete p space

```
:f { x; p; d; }
```

--If blank lines are absent in h space, then print p space and delete p space