# How to match two new lines (\n) instead of one, in regex?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a text file, Which is a dictionary containing over 80,000 words, I need to parse it someway or another, but first I need to sort it out, so I can parse it easily later. Is there a way in Regex where you can match two new lines instead of one? I.e. search the entire file looking for two new lines instead of one new line? Because there are two new lines after each new word in the dictionary.

The text format is like this throughout the entire file:

```
English : Pyramid of the Cerebellum

Section: Medical

Translation: ...

Description: ...


English: Pyramid

Section: General

Translation: ...

Description: ...
```

As you can see, there are 2 new lines after each word, so I want to find, all the new lines that are larger than 2... And then replace it using AWK, Is it possible?

I want the output to be like this:

```
English : Pyramid of the Cerebellum

Section: Medical

Translation: ...

Description: ...

English: Pyramid

Section: General

Translation: ...

Description: ...
```

Comment: Please post the expected output in your post too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Added.

Comment: I have never used AWK, but can't you just replace `\n{3,}` with `\n{2}`?

Comment: Although I think the question was interesting, I must convey the usual message here.  Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @kvantour To be honest I felt a little bit "sinful" posting this, Normally I post programming related questions, but this one I had no idea about it at all and didn't know where to post it.

Comment: Bulk downvotes happened on this post.

Comment: looks like you need to convert consecutive empty lines into one? `cat -s` is simplest solution if your version of cat supports it

Comment: @JamesWhiteley though possible, regardless of the tool you use to use a regexp for this would require reading the whole file into memory at once so we could then apply the regexp substitution which isn't efficient and may not even be possible if the input file is huge. It uses far less memory and is far more efficient to do this using awk as kvantour suggests, just reading 1 paragraph at a time.

Comment: @EdMorton that's a brilliant solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very quick way is using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n"}1' /path/to/your/file > /path/to/new/file
```

How does this work:

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) knowns the concept records (which is by default lines) and you can define a record by its record separator `RS`. If you set the value of `RS` to an empty string, it will match any multitude of empty lines as a record separator. The value `ORS` is the output record separator. It states which separator should be printed between two consecutive records. This is set to two <newline> characters. Finally, the statement `1` is a shorthand for `{print $0}` which prints the current record followed by the output record-separator `ORS`.

Comment: That worked, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '!/^$/{flag=""} /^$/{flag++} flag==2 && /^$/{next} 1'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too now.

```
awk '
!/^$/{              ##Checking if a line is NOT starting with blank space if yes then do following.
  flag=""           ##Nullifying value of variable flag here.
}                   ##Closing this blosk condition here.
/^$/{               ##Checking if a line starts with a blank line then do following.
  flag++            ##Incrementing value of variable flag with 1 here.
}                   ##Closing this bock condition here.
flag==2 && /^$/{    ##Checking condition here if variable flag value is 2 and line is empty then do following.
  next              ##next keyword is out of the box keyword for awk and will skip all further statements from here.
}                   ##Closing this block condition here.
1                   ##By mentioning 1 printing edited/non-edited line here.
' Input_file        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: It stays the same.

Comment: @Akar, could you please do a `cat -v Input_file` and let me know if you see control M characters? If they found remove them using `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file  && mv temp_file Input_file` let me know then?

Comment: That worked too, gave you an upvote! Thank you!

Comment: @RavinderSignh13 Is there a way to match only one new line? just one new line and not two lines, basically the reverse of this?

Comment: @Akar, could you please post samples for same in your post and let me know then?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following awk command:

```
awk '!NF&&!n{print;n=1}NF{print;n=0}' your_text_file
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: I've updated my answer so it can handle the case where your blank lines contain white spaces.

Comment: Still doesn't work, someone already answered my question, thanks!

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work for you, as it works well in my environment.

Comment: Thanks I see. Indeed I've been using gawk for so long that I forgot about the limitations of the regular awk. I've updated my answer to simply use `NF` instead, like the condition before it.