# Bash merge file lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file that holds output from a test.

```
test 1  
42  
test 2  
69  
test 3  
420  
test 4  
55378008
```

I would like to make the test output appear on the same line as the test name. like so:

```
test 1:    42  
test 2:    69  
test 3:    420  
test 4:    55378008
```

I am sure there is some fancy `sed`, `awk` or `perl` way to do this but I am stuck.

Comment: The file is not double spaced!

Comment: You are right, the title was misleading. I think "Merge file lines" may be a better title

Comment: It's not just the (old) title, it's also "I am aware of how sed G double spaces a file, I was hoping for a possible inverse of the sed G command to un-double space a file" really has nothing to do with what you want done.

Comment: @user3439894 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549402/how-to-find-continuous-blank-lines-and-convert-them-to-one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And here is another one in sed flavor to complete the offer :

```
sed 'N ; s/\n/: /' input_file
```

For each (odd) line starting from the first, append the next (even) one in pattern space separated by a LF, then just replace this LF by `:`.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'FNR%2{printf "%s: ", $0; next}1' file
```

This prints odd lines with suffix `:`  and without newline and even lines with a newline.

Answer (score 3):

`pr` has this built-in, but if you need whitespace adjustment as well, then `sed/awk/perl` solutions suggested in other answers will suit you better

```
$ pr -2ats': ' ip.txt 
test 1: 42
test 2: 69
test 3: 420
test 4: 55378008
```

This combines 2 lines at a time with `:`  as the separator.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the line feed of odd lines with `:␠`.

```
perl -pe's/\n/: / if $. % 2'
```

You have mentioned that you want to removing leading and trailing whitespace as well. For that, you can use the following:

```
perl -pe's/^\h+|\h+$/g; s/\n/: / if $. % 2'
```

[Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924)

Comment: I like `\h+` to remove only horizontal whitespace.  There's also the `\N` character class to mean not a newline.

Comment: @brian d foy, Excellent suggestion

Answer (score 1):

A shell solution, which is `very slow` on large set of data/files.

```
while IFS= read -r odd_line; do
  IFS= read -r even_line
  printf '%s: %s\n' "$odd_line" "$even_line"
done < file.txt
```

On the other hand if the colon is not a requirement `paste` can do the job.

```
paste - - < file.txt
```

Comment: `paste -d : - - < file`

Comment: Right, but it does not create a space. in between. at least on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Bash solution

> skips empty lines
>
> process both UNIX/DOS format 'end of line'
>
> accepts filename as argument or otherwise reads data from STDIN

```
#!/bin/bash

while read p1
do
  [[ -z $p1 ]] && continue
  # p1=`echo -n $p1 | tr -d "\r"`  # replaced with following line
  p1=${p1//$'\r'/}
  read p2
  echo -n "$p1: $p2"
done < ${1:-/dev/stdin}
```

Output

```
test 1: 42
test 2: 69
test 3: 420
test 4: 55378008
```

NOTE: no empty lines allowed between lines for join

Comment: you can try `p1=${p1//$'\r'/}` instead.

Comment: @Jetchisel -- hmm, it does work. Can you refer me where this 'construction' documented? I never seen it before.

Comment: Parameter Expansion  and `$' '` is a bash specific shell quoting.

Comment: @Jetchisel -- thank you, now it is a question how to memorize this construction or where I can find it. It is nice feature which very useful at some situations. I will change my answer to use your approach -- at least it will be a reference for future.

Comment: @Jetchisel -- Ok, I found where this construction is [described](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html).

Comment: It has more `/` that it should, should be `p1=${p1//$'\r'}` less the last `/` my bad sorry.

Comment: @Jetchisel -- double `//` has meaning more than one, `/` has meaning only one, both should work fine in this case (although `//` is excessive in this particular case).

Comment: I'm not talking about the `//` but the last `/`. I just showed you.